# Unable to delete data in CodeIgniter facing Fatal error

Tags: php, codeigniter, delete-row

**fetch_view.php**
This is my fetch_view.php file through this file I am showing my html.

```
<?php
    foreach ($h->result() as $row)
    { ?>
    <tr>    
        <td><?php echo $row->fname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->lname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->mobile; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->message; ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?= site_url('home/form').'/'.$row->id ?>">Edit</a></td>

        <td><a href="<?= site_url('home/delete').'/'.$row->id ?>">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

**select.php**
This is my model in this task.

```
public function deleteuser($id)     
{  
     $this->load->database();
     $this->db->where('id', $id);
     $this->db->delete('student');
     return true;
}


**home.php**
```

Controller function, In this file I am making a delete function.
[image], I have attached screenshot when I tried  to delete data I am facing that error.

```
public function delete()  
{
     $this->load->model('select');
     $id=$this->input->get('id');
     if($this->select->deleteuser($id))
     {
         $data['data']=$this->select->getuser();
         $this->load->view('fetch_view', $data);
     } 
}
```

Comment: where is your `getuser()` function?, You are calling `getuser()` with wrong way. If you have `getuser()` function in your home controller then you can call it by simply `$this->getuser()`.

Comment: Sir can I Edit my question and put my complete code of MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working fine but you don't have a getuser() function defined in your model 'select'.

> Note: When creating a model Please give name ending with "..._m" like "select_m" you will confuse about it later when your project will get larger.

Comment: getuser was wrong I have select(); function in my model $data['h']=$this->select->select();

Comment: public function select()  
      {  
         //data is retrive from this query 
       
         $query = $this->db->get('student');  
         return $query;  
      }

Comment: So you should use "return $query->row();" at the end of your select function.